# While loop in Java with Multiple conditions

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

Can someone help me figure out why the while statement isn't working? The loop does stop after i = 3 but won't stop if continueSurvey = 0. It runs but it won't quit the loop if I change continueSurvey to O. Even if I step into the processes and I can see that the variable is 0, the loop continues.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SurveyConductor 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Survey a = new Survey(); 
        a.display();

        a.enterQuestions();   

        int continueSurvey = 1;
        int i = 0;

            while ((continueSurvey != 0) && (i < 3))
            {

                for (int row = a.getRespID(); row < 3; row++)
                {

                    System.out.println("Respondent " + (row+1) + " Please tell us how you would rate our: ");

                    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                    {
                        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                        System.out.println(a.presentQuestion(col) + ": ");
                        System.out.println("Enter your response (1-Strongly Disagree, 2-Disagree, 3-Neutral, 4-Agree, 5-Strongly Agree): ");
                        int response = input.nextInt();

                        if ((response < 1) || (response >5))
                        {
                            while ((response < 1) || (response > 5))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Your response must be between 1 and 5. Please try again.");

                                System.out.println(a.presentQuestion(col) + ": ");
                                System.out.println("Enter your response (1-Strongly Disagree, 2-Disagree, 3-Neutral, 4-Agree, 5-Strongly Agree): ");
                                response = input.nextInt();
                            } 
                        }

                        a.logResponse(row,col,response);
                        System.out.println();
                    }

                    a.displaySurveyResults();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("The top rated question is Question #" + a.topRatedQuestion() + ".");
                    System.out.println("The bottom rated question is Question #" + a.bottomRatedQuestion() + ".");
                    System.out.println();

                    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Are there any more repondents (0 - No, 1 - Yes): ");
                    continueSurvey = input2.nextInt(); 


                    a.generateRespondentID();
                    i++;
                }
            } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `break` inside your `for` loop.  IE,

```
if(continueSurvey == 0)
    break;
```

This will exit the `for` loop and allow the `while` loop to exit.

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the accepted answer (Check mark to the left under the number)

Answer (score 0):

The part where you ask if the user wants to continue is inside this for loop

```
for (int row = a.getRespID(); row < 3; row++)
```

not just your while loop. This means it will keep asking until the for loop is done, only quitting when it finally gets back around to the while loop condition.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up putting the break statement in my code. I tried moving the question outside of the for loop but I needed it to ask the question before the next respondent was generated.

Comment: @MichelleAnderson Yep, that is probably the solution which makes the most sense :) Be sure to accept StormeHawke's answer, as that will help others who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition in the while loop is:

```
((continueSurvey != 0) && (i < 3))
```

which means that the inner block of the while loop will be executed if and only if continuSurvey != 0 and i < 3 in the same time. You have inner loops which have different conditions. I would search for the problem in the inner loops using a debugger. If this answer is not enough for you, then please specify what would you want to achieve.